# Table of four columns (x,y,z, value) to matrix table

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007, pivot-table

I would like convert data that is in four columns to a matrix table. I've tried to use OFFSET function and it works but my data is too large (about 100,000 cells) and it crashed.

So, I wound like to try to do this by macro, can you suggest how to do this? Or you have any better suggestion that would be great.

PS. I used OFFSET formula from this site [here](https://superuser.com/questions/569185/convert-a-table-of-3-columns-of-x-y-value-to-the-matrix-table).

[image: Picture here]

Comment: Have you tried a pivot table or if you have so many records, Power Pivot (Excel 2010 or later)?

Comment: My computer that uses to calculate this data is Excel 2007. :(

Comment: Your picture shows only unique sets of 3 for the 3 descriptive columns.  Is is always that way (for all rows) or do you get repeats with another value, and do you then sum the values.  Please add more detail.

Comment: It has another value for data (more than 3) but I don't want to sum the value

Comment: @pnuts : it seem pt works fine, but can you explain more about row that must be added which you mentioned on the last part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fun problem! Because you were having problems involving the size of your data, I tried to avoid using objects like dictionaries(I don't know how much a dictionary can hold). Instead I created a program that keeps track of very little data, but ends up continuously reading/writing from the file: It'll be very slow, but it'll work for very large files.

Anyways, try copying and pasting the following code into a VBA module and then run it on your file. You may need to change some of the values for the rows and columns.

EDIT: I made it work for the example picture you gave, but it's a mess. I'll try to make it clearer tomorrow (g2g)
EDIT: It's been updated! Carefully commented etc, It'll be easy to modify however you like.

Summary

- Build matrix table below data table
- Loop through the rows of the data table and add them to the matrix table
- If the matrix table does not already have a row or column for the data, make it, else place in existing

Example:
 [image]

Code: (SO got rid of the whitespace :( I think my post is too long)

```
'Start and end row of the original data
Private dataStartRow As Long
Private dataEndRow As Long

'The start row/column of the matrix
Private matrixStartRow As Long
Private matrixStartCol As Long

'How many rows/columns in the matrix
Private matrixRowLength As Long
Private matrixColLength As Integer

Public Sub makeMatrixTable()
    'Sets initial values for variables
    initializeValues
    'Builds table
    buildTable
End Sub

Private Function initializeValues()
    'The actual data probably begins on row 2, because row 1 is usually used for column titles
    dataStartRow = 2
    'Get last row of data
    dataEndRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

    'By adding 2, we create a gap row between our new matrix table and the original data table
    matrixStartRow = dataEndRow + 2
    'The matrix values begin after column 2, because columns 1&2 are used for titles
    matrixStartCol = 2

    matrixRowLength = 0
    matrixColLength = 0
End Function

Private Function buildTable()
    Dim dataRow As Long
    Dim matrixRow As Long
    Dim matrixCol As Integer
    Dim value As String

    'The keys are the column/row titles
    'I'm using the work "key" because we're mimicking a dictionary object by only using a key once
    'in this case it's a little more complicated, as we have 3 keys (2 row keys, 1 column key)
    Dim rowKey1 As String, rowKey2 As String
    Dim colKey As String

    'loop through all rows containing data
    For dataRow = dataStartRow To dataEndRow
        'get keys from data
        rowKey1 = CStr(ActiveSheet.Cells(dataRow, 1).value)
        rowKey2 = CStr(ActiveSheet.Cells(dataRow, 3).value)
        colKey = CStr(ActiveSheet.Cells(dataRow, 2).value)

        'find if we have already created rows for the row keys, and if so return the row (else -1)
        matrixRow = rowExistsInMatrix(rowKey1, rowKey2)
        'find if we have already created a column for the column key, and if so return the row (else -1
        matrixCol = colExistsInMatrix(colKey)

        'Our matrix does not have a row with those row keys, so we must create one
        If matrixRow = -1 Then
            'increase the size of our matrix
            matrixRowLength = matrixRowLength + 1
            'get row that is not in use
            matrixRow = matrixStartRow + matrixRowLength
            'add the new keys to matrix
            ActiveSheet.Cells(matrixRow, 1).value = rowKey1
            ActiveSheet.Cells(matrixRow, 2).value = rowKey2
        End If

        'We don't have a column that matches the column key
        If matrixCol = -1 Then
            'increase size of matrix table
            matrixColLength = matrixColLength + 1
            'get column that is not in use
            matrixCol = matrixStartCol + matrixColLength
            'add new key to matrix
            ActiveSheet.Cells(matrixStartRow, matrixCol).value = colKey
        End If

        'get the value to be placed in the matrix from column 4
        value = CStr(ActiveSheet.Cells(dataRow, 4).value)
        'place value
        ActiveSheet.Cells(matrixRow, matrixCol).value = value

    Next dataRow
End Function

'Checks to see if the key from the data table exists in our matrix table
'if it does, return the row in the matrix table
'else return -1
Private Function rowExistsInMatrix(dataKey1 As String, dataKey2 As String) As Long
    Dim matrixRow As Long
    Dim matrixKey1 As String, matrixKey2 As String

    'loop through rows of matrix
    For matrixRow = matrixStartRow To matrixStartRow + matrixRowLength
        'get keys from matrix
        matrixKey1 = CStr(ActiveSheet.Cells(matrixRow, 1).value)
        matrixKey2 = CStr(ActiveSheet.Cells(matrixRow, 2).value)

        'do the keys match
        If dataKey1 = matrixKey1 And dataKey2 = matrixKey2 Then
            rowExistsInMatrix = matrixRow
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next matrixRow

    rowExistsInMatrix = -1
End Function

'Same as rowExistsInMatrix but loops through column titles
Private Function colExistsInMatrix(dataKey As String) As Long
    Dim matrixKey As String
    Dim matrixCol As Integer

    'loop through columns
    For matrixCol = matrixStartCol To matrixStartCol + matrixColLength
        matrixKey = CStr(ActiveSheet.Cells(matrixStartRow, matrixCol).value)

        'does a key match
        If matrixKey = dataKey Then
            colExistsInMatrix = matrixCol
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next matrixCol

    colExistsInMatrix = -1
End Function
```

Comment: Whoops! I just noticed you posted an Image besides the reference link. My answer was based on the reference link, so I will have to update it for your image

Comment: Right now I can fix this problem with PT, but I still expect to see your code :)

Answer (score 2):

Pivoted with Type above Gear for ROWS, Color for COLUMNS and Sum of Amount for Σ VALUES:

[image: SO24317683 example]

with the top row hidden, the Report Layout shown in Tabular Form, all subtotals and totals removed, the order of columns and of rows rearranged, empty cells set to show `0`, expand/collapse buttons hidden, Repeat All Item Labels set `*`, and borders added.

In order to show the row of `0`s, I added Bus/Green/Manual to the source data (with a colour (Green) to avoid (blank) as an extra column).

---

`*` not available in Excel 2007. To repeat item labels for versions earlier than Excel 2010 the standard practice is to copy the PT and Paste Special, Values and fill the blanks by selecting them with Go To Special, Blanks then `=`, Up, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.